# Sharepoint webpart views

Tags: sharepoint

I'm looking for a way to let users select pre-defined views in a documents library webpart. As far as I know, if I want to put extra information on the page, I have to use the webpart. But then the view selection disappears.

[Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azkXH.png) [No buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0bML.png)

Any ideas?

Kind regards, Johan

Edit: added pictures

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I need more details on your question. Could you tell me what is extra information and what webpart you usedto put it on the page? And what do you mean by
"the view selection disappears"?

Do you mean the bwlow button disappears?
[image]

We can set default view by editing the document library.

[image]

Comment: I want to add a line of text pointing to som rules people have to follow. The webpart I used is the Documents webpart. The toolbar buttons are not the problem. It is more the view selection buttons like 'All Documents', 'New Documents', etc.